# Reading Regex and strings from app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to read regex from **app.config** file

if I try to read strings it is working fine but,
if I try to get the regex Pattern it is not accepting my pattern

Here my code is

```
<appSettings>
<add key="regex" value=@"^(?<TicketNum>\w{3}-\d+)\s+(?<Message>.+?)$"></add>
<add key="getString" value="siva"/>;
</appSettings>
```

Am I missed anything?

Comment: no need for `@` in config file

Comment: And what do you mean with not accepting that pattern? Does your app throw some exception?

Comment: Yaa it is throwing like "tag was not closed" because of  <TicketNum>

Comment: @SivamohanReddy - It will not build you need to escape the XML characters in the App.Config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape `<` and `>` in your xml, try this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="regex" value="^(?&lt;TicketNum&gt;\w{3}-\d+)\s+(?&lt;Message&gt;.+?)$"/>
</appSettings>
```

[Escaping XML Data](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EscapingData.aspx). Here:

[image]

Also no need for the `@` sign.

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to escape `>` in attribute, but won't hurt anyway.

Comment: From the OPs error is *is* neccessary to escape the tags. The file must be valid xml, so every string within the value should be escaped correctly.

Comment: @Evk :`<` it is important, try it out it won't build

Comment: But I didn't say anything about `<`, only about `>`.

Comment: @Evk - okay i understood now.

Comment: Old post but same issue. Would it work to uuencode it then store in config?